# NameError: name 'x' is not defined(Python 3.7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

I am new to python ,
I am learning "if and else" condition in python 3.7.

So the issue is , when I type my this code

```
def age_group(user_age):
    x = int(input("Enter your age :"))
    return x

if x < 150 :
    print(age_group(x))
else :
    print("Either he is GOD or he is dead")
```

But after executing I get an NameError:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\Enter Age.py", line 6, in <module>
if x < 150 :
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Comment: Your code is not legal python.  You need to fix indenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `x` only exists in the scope of `age_group`. Variables used in functions in Python typically exist only in that scope unless you use the `global` keyword or do some other trickery. Either way, you should return that value to the caller and assign it to a variable. Working example (I also removed one unused argument):

```
def age_group():
  return int(input("Enter your age :"))

x = age_group()
if x < 150:
  print(x)
else:
  print('Either he is GOD or he is dead')
```